# How can I get a View from a Layout?

Tags: android, layout, view, xamarin, layout-inflater

I am using `Xamarin` and have a question about getting a `View` from a `Layout`.

If I have a `Layout` called `custom_info_window`, how can I get a `View` from this?

I have tried this code:

`View v = Inflate(Resource.Layout.custom_info_window, null);`

This is the error I am getting:

> Error CS0103: The name 'Inflate' does not exist in the current context

Can I please have some help with this?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

Here is my code for the inflater:

```
LayoutInflater inflater =(LayoutInflater)Context.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
Error CS0120: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Android.Content.Context.GetSystemService(string)'
```

Comment: You need to use layout inflator..actually inflate is a sub function of layout inflator class. for more refer http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use this one..

```
 LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);
 var layout = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.custom_info_window, layoutImages) as LinearLayout;
```

Comment: Have you make any custom view??

Comment: Yes I have made a custom view.

Answer (score 1):

```
LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View v = mInflater.inflate((Resource.Layout.custom_info_window, null);
```

Answer (score 1):

it should be also possible to get a LayoutInflater from the context, something like:

```
 LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext()).inflate(Resource.Layout.custom_info_window, null);
```

Comment: This seems the simplest way.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a Context object to get the service. If nothing else works, use static property Application.Context:

```
var inflater = Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService) as LayoutInflater;
var view = inflater.Inflate(...
```